# probability ratio question

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

From n men and n women one wants to select k male and k female candidates, to create either a committee or a ballot. In a ballot the members are fully ranked (first, second, ...); in a committee they remain unranked. 
Let Bk be the number of possible ballots and Ck - the number of possible committees. Find the ratio Bk/Ck.

(k!)2  **or** (2k)! **or** k out of 2k?

My Thoughts:
(2k)! would be the answer, as men and women selection process is the same.
So the only difference between the two process is ranking.

Could anyone advise on my answer? thank you.

Comment: Your answer looks convincing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to have exactly k women and k men, so you have to choose them separately. The answer thus must be $\frac{(nPk)^2}{(nCk)^2}$

which equals $\frac{(n!)^2}{(n-k)!^2}\cdot\frac{k!^2\cdot(n-k)!^2}{(n!)^2} = (k!)^2$